# How to increase quota over 1000 requests per day of map javascript api

Tags: api, google-maps

I added a visa account to enable billing but was limited to 1000 requests per day. While I need about 20,000 requests per day, I can't set quota them because they only import 0 to 1000.
Please help me ! Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such limit as `1000 requests per day`; just see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing#pricing-for-the-maps-javascript-api).

```
20.000 requests * 30 days = 600.000 requests per month.
```

`> 500.000 requests per month` it reads: [contact sales](https://enterprise.google.com/maps/contact-form/index.html) for volume pricing.